# Sending marketing cloud mails from Salesforce instantly

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, automationstudio, triggered-send

We have a unique problem in Sending marketing cloud mails from Salesforce.

Contact records are available in Salesforce and the logic to select which contact should receive the marketing cloud mail is determined based on a complex apex logic. This apex code updates a custom object with the list of contacts and the content they have to receive. We tried the below approaches:

1. Triggered send approach - got hit with future send limitation (only 50 allowed). As per marketing cloud documentation, triggered send is not supported for bulk updates.
2. Journey Builder approach - Marketing cloud is injecting Salesforce contacts from custom object record by record and not in bulk mode.

Can some one let me know encountered similar issue where in mail needs to be send from marketing cloud for 1000+ Salesforce contacts at the same time when a record is inserted (real time/ near real time).

Comment: Have you tried the triggered sends on the SF side?

Comment: Is the apex logic that determines the 1000+ audience also in real-time?  I'm trying to understand why this couldn't be a batch automation.

Comment: Hi @Data_Kid , yes am using the triggered send from SF side.

Comment: @DavidDevoy yes, apex ogic is written to determine 1000+ audience. (ie) records get created. And as soon as the record gets created, we need to pass the records to MC and thereby send mails in real-time (or) near real-time.

Comment: It seems like a Salesforce Send that references a report would be better for this large of a dataset.  But, you would need some way to trigger the Salesforce Send.  Automation Studio can deploy a Salesforce Send on a scheduled based or triggered via a file drop on the FTP.  Maybe you can some how trigger the automation in real-time.

Comment: Oh, you can also run an automation by using the SFMC SOAP API, but this would require making an API call from APEX.  I don't have the background knowledge on how to do that.  :)

Comment: @DavidDevoy Thanks for the above. Am expecting a sample code which can be used in Salesforce to drop csv files containing record details in FTP location, which MC can listen to and fetch files from there. Or a sample code to be used in Salesforce to interact directly with MC Data Extension and create records in there in real time.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  But, this code sample would be in apex (not really my background).  I would recommend posting a new question which include the apex tag.

Comment: Out of curiosity - is there a reason that this process lives in APEX ? Could you not simply sync the various objects to MC and then achieve the same using SQL queries, and then, depending on email requirements - use 1 or multiple send tables combined with 1 email with dynamic content/ampscript or multiple emails? It would also save you the storage of the various records. Alternatively, if it has to be via Salesforce, typically you would have an integration layer (Jitterbit, Dell Boomi etc.) that could do this processing for you, and call the MC Soap API?